# Unicode bullet point prints as question mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I am trying to list some things in an alert, when I use \u2022 directly in an alert it does a bullet correctly, but when I do this in my scriptlet:

```
for(int i=0; i < programs.length; i++) {
  collegesWoRecvDate += "\u2022  " + programs[i] + " \n";
}
```

And this in my HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="collegesWoRecvDate" id="collegesWoRecvDate" value="<%=collegesWoRecvDate%>" />
```

And this in my jQuery:

```
var noRecvDateArray = $('#collegesWoRecvDate').val();

var missingDates = "MESSAGE MESSAGE \n\n" +
                     noRecvDateArray + "\n" +
                    "MESSAGE MESSAGE" +
alert(missingDates);
```

The alert prints out like this:

"MESSAGE MESSAGE

? program 1

? program 2

? program 3

MESSAGE MESSAGE"

Why does it do this?  How would I change it back to a bullet?

Comment: Are you sure that your pages are being served as UTF-8? You're building a Unicode string in the server for that markup, but if the page is delivered to the client such that the client thinks it's a different encoding, you could get that problem.

Comment: @Pointy I am not sure, honestly. I figured the problem was something similar to this, but I am not sure how to address it.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools to check the HTTP headers sent with responses from your server. The "Content-Type" header is what you want to look for. If it's UTF-8, then the problem is something else.

Comment: That was the problem - it was iso-8859-1 -  I changed to utf-8 and it worked in firefox, Ill try in other browsers. Thanks for the help.  If you post an answer I will mark as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* your page makes it from the server to the browser marked as being UTF-8 encoded, then everything *should* work. (Your server-side template  code looks like JSP, but whatever it is I'm assuming that it's something that works in Unicode.) Thus, you're building a proper Unicode bullet character, and you're dropping it into some HTML, and that should be fine. Then, in the browser, when your JavaScript code pulls it back out of the element, it should still be correct.

However, if the page is sent to the browser marked with a character encoding other than UTF-8, then the browser will misinterpret that HTML. Then the JavaScript will retrieve a mangled version of the string and you'll see the effect that you do.

You can check the response headers with developer tools and, if incorrect, fix them in your server in a way that depends on the particular server environment (should be pretty easy).